# Git rebase on public branches?

Tags: git

I'm fairly new to Git Rebase, but i think i understand the whole idea behind it and how it works.
However, there's one point i'm still confused about.

Using the git rebase workflow, when i'm ready to add my changes to a `master` branch, i would run:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout feature_branch
git rebase master
```

and then what?
i read somewhere that to add my changes on top of `master`, i need to then do:

```
git checkout master
git rebase feature_branch
```

is this true? (to complete applying my changes)
It doesn't make sense to me since the "golden rule of rebase" is to not run it on public branches (`master`, in this case, which is shared by many developers)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something simpler

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
```

I personally never use pull, I preferc and recommend to use feth

After you should push your branch and submit a merge request or pull request.
If you can push on master directly without MR ou PR process:

```
git checkout master
git merge --ff-only feature_branch
git push
```

Comment: I guess using `--ff-only` means there will be no merge commit for this merge, and only the commits of `feature_branch` added on top of `master`'s?

Comment: Yes, this is fast forward only

Comment: I think we are mixing two questions here. 1: pull and 2: push.    You were correct to be suspicious of the idea of rebasing master. That is definitely a no-no. The point Gambit2007 is making is that you don't rebase your code into master. You do some sort of merge. I.E. Pull request, local merge, fast-forward merge.